# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError - different versions of JDK and JRE

Tags: java, javac

when I'm trying to compile my class(hello.java) - it's ok - no problems, but when I trying to run hello.class - I have this trouble 
my java version 1.8.0_211
my javac version 12.0.1
I have installed JDK 12
How to fix it?

my JDK path: D:\jdk-12.0.1\bin

```
C:\Users\Vasyl\Desktop>javac hello.java

C:\Users\Vasyl\Desktop>java hello
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: hello has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Check yours JRE (Java Runtime Environment). You might have an older one lingering on yours pc. A JDK ships with a JRE, but that is not used if there is already a JRE on the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable as below:

```
JAVA_HOME=D:\jdk-12.0.1
```

and then add the following part to the **beginning** of the value of your `PATH` environment variable:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin;
```

This ensures that this JDK version would be picked up for both compile and runtime execution of your program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same version of JDK and JRE.

Ex:-
**Problem**
JDK version 14, JRE version 8
This is the problem.

Fix:-
Make sure you have the same version of JRE and JDK.

Step1:
Open CMD
run these commands "javac -version" without quotes.
then "java -version"

step2:
If you have different versions of JDK and JREs. Uninstall JRE.
Make sure to keep only one JDK.

Step3:
Go to environment variables.

Set the path of your JDK.

EX:-
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1

[Take a look at this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAfjw.jpg)

Note:- JDK includes the same version of JDK and JRE. Just download JDK from oracle.com.